# samsung ssd is not showing up as available

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, opensuse

I have recently bought HP Proliant 360 gen7 which came with 4 X 146 G drives. I also bought 2 Samsung 850 Evo drives each with 250 G. The server it self doesn't have an OS and i am trying to boot from a USB to install vicibox, which comes with Opensuse OS. I cant find the drives anywhere. I started the installation and they weren't showing up. I even did

> df-h

and  they still were not showing up. Any help would be great. My ultimate goal is to have the ssd drives installed to increase speed and space for recordings so that the server does not crash.

Comment: Does the server have all the latest firmware/BIOS updates?

Comment: that I am not sure. I bought it as refurbished from amazon. Is there a way once in bios to check if it is updated?

Comment: I had a very unpleasant experience with OpenSuse in terms of hardware support. If you are given a choice, try a different distro. For the server even Debian would be better IMO.

Comment: yea i agree i usually never use opensuse. I stick with centos or ubuntu. But for vicibox to install everything it comes with opensuse unfortunately. The only other option I could do is to install vicidial from scratch but there are too many things that could go wrong .

Comment: Yes, you can check the BIOS version inside the BIOS, I'm sure. Moreover you should be able to get a utility from HP that will download all the latest firmware repositories and create an ISO from that for a USB flash drive, then boot the server to it and it will update all firmware and the BIOS (at least that's how Dell does it).

Comment: I agree with @andselisk though, it sounds like OpenSUSE doesn't have the correct SATA drivers to see the SSD.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem might be with the necessity to setup a logical drive through RAID controller firmware first.

When you connected the drives the RAID controller probably sees them, however since you haven't set them up as Logical Drives of any kind they are not presented to the OS and that's why you are unable to access them.

Check during POST if any messages like "press ctrl+r to enter RAID utility" or similiar appear, and if they do - press that combination to enter the RAID setup firmware and add the drives as Logical Drives.

If you want them separate, set them up as separate RAID 0 configurations.

Comment: Also, the controller (or ports) could be disabled in the BIOS or set to an unusual mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few relevant web pages.

http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/archives_Division/13598_div_v33/13598_div.HTML
This one suggests you cannot have more than four hard drive active if you have a CD or DVD.

http://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04284501.pdf?ver=56

https://www.hpe.com/h20195/V2/Getdocument.aspx?docname=c04284501